# php curl fetch mysql data - returning only one row

Tags: php, mysql, curl

i am using curl to fetch mysql data from my one site to another. The codes are

```
$ch = curl_init();
$myurl = "http://domain.com/account.php?siteid=$siteid";
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $myurl);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $siteref);

$file_contents = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$data=unserialize($file_contents);
print_r($data);
```

the code on `account.php` of other site is

```
$q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `".$siteid."`");
$data=mysql_fetch_array($q);
echo serialize($data);
```

the problem is i am getting only the first record from the table. I want the entire contents of the table sent back. how can i do that?

Comment: Loop in your rows `while($data = mysql_fetch_array($q)) { //print here }`

Comment: thank you all for so much insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a loop to store each array. mysql_fetch_array returns only one row at a time.

```
while ($data=mysql_fetch_array($q)) {
     $dataRows[] = $data;
}
echo serialize($dataRows);
```

Also, all mysql functions are now deprecated. Take a look at [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) and [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](http://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_array):

> mysql_fetch_array — Fetch a result row as an associative array, a numeric array, or both

Unless you're looping over the result from `mysql_query`, you're only ever going to get one row.  Try something along the lines of:

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `" . $siteid . "`");
$data = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($q)) {
   $data[] = $row;
}
```

However, look at that docs page again and you'll notice a big red **WARNING** indicating that you should no longer use the mysql extension.  Instead you should build your application using [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Answer (score 0):

This goes in your `account.php` file:

(to pull multiple records off database you should use loops)

```
    $q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `".$siteid."`");
    if(mysql_num_rows($q) >= 1) {
       while($data = mysql_fetch_array($q)) {
          echo serialize($data);
       }
    } else { echo "there are no rows"; }
```

also using `mysql_num_rows` is a good fail-safe method.

---

as of PHP 5.4 all `mysql_` functions have been deprecated, they are not secure and no longer recommended, consider using `PDO` or `mysqli` instead!

Answer (score 0):

You are only fetching one row of data from the result set.  If you want all rows, you will need to read out the result set in a loop construct. that typically looks something like this:

```
$q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `".$siteid."`");
$data = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($q)) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
echo serialize($data);
```

A few important notes:

- You should not be using `mysql_*` functions as they are deprecated. Consider using `mysqli` or `PDO` instead.
- Though not shown, I am guessing that you currently have an SQL injection vulnerability, so you need to make sure you cleanse `$siteid` before using it in a query.
- You really should add error handling to your script.  Check for cases when the query fails or the database connection fails and handle them appropriately.